# How to handle In-App purchase was complete outside the app (maybe in itunes app)?

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase

I have an auto-renew subscription type in-app purchase product developed under iOS7.
Sometime user may not have billing information.
Therefore, after tapping purchase button, users will be redirected to itunes app for complete their billing information.
After they finished it, the purchase confirm dialog will show up.
Users tapped "Confirm" to do purchase but they were not redirected back to my app.
Instead, they needed to open my app by themselves.
And the un-completed transaction didn't come back neither.
It doesn't make sense. Does anybody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found another phenomenon. Auto-renew subscription in sandbox will renew 5 times automatically. Few month ago, I can receive unfinished purchase transactions when I launch my app. But now, I receive nothing back unless I do restore action. That's so weird.

Comment: I'm sure that [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver] was invoked. Did I miss anything else?